# Gears Lubrication and Cooling

Tags: tribology

1-Is there any lubrication mode other than boundary lubrication and EHL which may be applied in the design of the power transmission system?
2-Which type of technologies have been used traditionally for generating aforesaid lubrication modes in gear trains?
3-what is the difference of the aforesaid lubrication modes based on their cooling performance?

Comment: Which is "the power transmission system"?

Comment: The gearbox that transmit the power from high-speed rotor of the gas turbine to other units

Comment: Then you need to add some detail, some may have been thinking it was a cvt for a Daf 55 or a gearbox for a 2CV…

Comment: I am talking about accessory drive which takes the power from high speed shaft of a gas turbine to drive accessories such as pumps, generators........etc

Comment: Even more detail that you should add to the question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Gears are surface-lubricated

I've never heard of another method, but someone out there might be creating oil channels to individual gear teeth like a journal.

Normal lube is grease for low speed, splash oil, and forced oil.  Splash and forced are just two ways to get oil onto the teeth.  Forced can be mist, drip, spray, or stream.  All of these are just different ways to get oil onto the gear tooth.  Generally, the mode is selected based on tangential speed.  Temperature affects the oil selection.

Temperature control will be easier for forced since there is a pump that can move the lubricant through a cooler.  Fins on the gearbox would work for any oil method.

Comment: Even boxes without forced lubrication can have a pump and cooler.

Comment: Tiger Guy, I appreciate your explanation, would you mind if I email some pages of service publication regarding accessory drive of particular aviation gas turbine for more detail discussion?

Comment: can I email the technical document pages?